# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая после "вот"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частицы

*Вот, чему мы научились!* (Под "вот" подразумевается результат работы.)

Comment: К сожалению, это то, чего нет в правилах.

Answer (score 4):

***Вот чему мы научились!***

В таких конструкциях запятая не ставится.

> [**ВОТ, *частица.***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&all=x) <...> **2.** *(обычно ударная) (с местоим. и нареч.).* Употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в целом. *Вот что я тебе скажу. Вот по какому поводу мы собрались. Вот на кого надежда. Вот в чём вопрос.*

Вот [ответы портала "Грамота.ру"](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%28%2C%29), где говорится, что запятая не нужна.

Comment: А бывает, что там паузу надо. Есть два варианта произношения.

Comment: @oleedd Ну и что, что пауза. Она, кстати, при "обычно ударной" частице почти всегда есть. Запятую поставим здесь: "Вóт, мы научились" Или не поставим: "Вот мы научи́лись". А еще вы недавно писали, что не надо всегда по паузам и ударениям писать.

Comment: Да, потому что иногда это вводит в заблуждение ("позволяет" делать то, что нельзя), но не здесь. Просто есть два варианта произношения в таких случаях (ударная и безударная), отличаются существенно. А они всё уравняли.